# What does the phrase "do whatever I want" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

From a [NY Times interview with Matty Healy](https://www.nytimes.com/2022/09/08/arts/music/1975-matty-healy-being-funny-in-a-foreign-language.html):

> Q: What are your commercial ambitions these days? Do you think it would be fun for the 1975 to have a No. 1 hit or a TikTok moment?
>
> A: It’s difficult to be big and say — genuinely — that I have zero commercial ambition. There’s definitely a “if it ain’t broke, don’t fix it” kind of thing, which is where, listen, we’ve never known what to do and we’ve never tried to do anything. So the second we stop doing that, we’ll probably [expletive] up. I tend to say no to stuff for money.
> I don’t know how you can write this up without it being rude or inappropriate, but I just got offered a four-month tour next year of stadiums with the biggest singer-songwriter in the world that would’ve made me money that I’ve never even seen or heard of in my life.
>
> Q: Ed Sheeran?
>
> A: Yeah. And **I got offered to be main support and do whatever I want.** Think about the money you think I’m getting offered — it’s not just offered, it’s what he can afford because of what he makes for shows — and then just triple it. It’s insane. The thing that’s stopped me just doing that is because — I don’t care. It’s not worth it. Not because I don’t like Ed Sheeran. I think he’s, in a lot of ways, a genius. And he does what he does better than anybody else. But opening up for somebody and not just being real, that’s the kind of stuff I think about.

I’d like to understand the sentence in bold above: ‘**I got offered to be main support and do whatever I want.**’

What isn’t really clear to me is the latter phrase, **‘and do whatever I want.’**
Does it mean that he got offered to open for Ed Sheeran and do whatever he wants to play live as a main support there? Or and do whatever he wants to do afterwards by the huge amount of money he’d get by supporting him?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's ambiguous, as you've discovered, but it almost certainly means they were offered the position with freedom to do whatever he wanted in the show. This implies that it's common for a massive act like Sheeran to dictate to his opening acts what he wants them to do in their shows, but in this case, he didn't.

My certainty comes from the context and the way the sentence was spoken. If Healy had meant he'd have the freedom that lots of money gives, he almost certainly would have said, "I got offered to be main support and **then I could** do whatever I want."

Comment: I didn’t know it’d be ‘then I could’ if he meant the second meaning I guessed. Thanks so much. It helps me a lot.